# Taylor expansion of $\log(1+ix)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

How do I obtain the Taylor expansion of $\log(1+ix)$ around $x=0$? I know how to do it for $\log(1+z)$ if $z$ is a real number. But how do I do it (formally correct) in the case of the complex argument $ix$? How do I compute the appropriate derivatives. Moreover, how can I show that the remainder of the second-order Taylor expansion satisfies $\vert r_2(x)\vert\leq 1$ for $\vert x \vert < 1$? Many thanks for any sort of help!

Comment: The key to this question is that the notion of differentiation can be appropriately expanded to describe functions over complex numbers.  We would say that the function $\log(1 + z)$ is holomorphic(complex-differentiable) in a neighborhood of $z=0$, allowing us to describe $\log(1 + z)$ by its Taylor expansion.

Comment: thanks for the help. any ideas about the remainder? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The complex expansion

$$\log{(1+z)} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k \, z^k}{k+1} $$

converges for all $|z| \lt 1$.  Thus, the series applies to $z=i x$ so long as $|x| \lt 1$.  You may derive the derivatives from term-by-term differentiation if need be, or by direct differentiation of the log.

Comment: many thanks for your help. do you also have any hints on how to bound the remainder of the expansion? many thanks again, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

About bounding the remainder: going off of Ron's formula for the Taylor expansion, the Remainder from a second order approximation is
$$
r_2(z) = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k \, z^k}{k+1}
$$
We might be able to prove that $|r_2(z)|<1$ for $z=ix$ with $-1< x <1$ as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
|r_2(z)| &= \left|\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k \, z^k}{k+1}\right|\\
&= \left|\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-i)^k \, x^k}{k+1}\right| \\
&= \left|
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-i)^{2j} \, x^{2j}}{2j+1} + 
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-i)^{2j+1} \, x^{2j+1}}{2j+2} 
\right|\\
&= \left|
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j} \, x^{2j}}{2j+1} - 
i\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j} \, x^{2j+1}}{2j+2} 
\right|\\
& \leq \left|
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j} \, x^{2j}}{2j+1}\right| + 
\left|\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j} \, x^{2j+1}}{2j+2} 
\right|\\
&< \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j}}{2j+1} + 
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{j}}{2j+2} 
\end{align}
$$
I think it is possible to find a bound for these sums in turn.  They certainly converge, though I am not immediately sure how to place a good bound on them.